# Automate php script using javasctipt

Tags: javascript, php

What is the easiest way to automate php script to read 1000s of links in a file and produce output?

I have this php code to read links whether they're valid or not. Currently I copy/paste `max 500 links` in the `urls.txt` file each time and it produce results, my server do not handle more than that. I need to check `15-20K links`.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("urls.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $link = trim($line);
        $isValid = CheckLinks($link);
        if($isValid){
            echo "$link". "<br>";

        }else{
            echo "";
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "Could not read urls.txt";
} 

function CheckLinks($link) {
    $url = $link;
    $extpage = file_get_contents($url);
    $notValid = strpos($extpage,"This page doesn't exists.");

    return !$notValid;
}
?>
```

What should be added to it to check this amount of links?

Edit: I want it to read 400-500 lines and give output and then next 500 lines and so on.

I'm newbie so forgive me if I ask too much.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: That won't work in my case, as it will delay whole script and when it will start it again load all links which will result in timeout. I want it to read 500 lines and give output and then next 500 lines.

Comment: As I said in my answer, use a counter for that; if time limit is a problem then http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0):

You can put the script to [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) after each check:

```
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $link = trim($line);
    $isValid = CheckLinks($link);
    if($isValid){
        echo "$link<br>";
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
    sleep(1); // add this line
}
```

If 1 second sleep for each iteration is too much, you could use a counter which you increment up to the number of checks you want to perform, then sleep some seconds and reset the counter.

Lastly, if time limit is a problem, you can use [`set_time_limit(0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to remove the limit altogether.